# What exactly does the new function do, and what does is this line saying exactly?

Tags: java

I want to know what the "new" function does in java exactly. Also, what is going on in line 8?

I am brand new to java and have a little experience in coding, but i just want to know exactly what is going on.

```
Star[] stars = new Star[1200];

void settings() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
   stars[i] = new Star(); 
  }
}

void draw() {
 background(0);
 translate(width/2, height/2); 
 for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
   stars[i].update();
   stars[i].show();
  }
}
```

This code along with another small file is supposed to make a scene with stars moving toward you. It does this, however, I am confused with what the I < stars.length and i++ is doing as well as what the new Star[1200] is doing.

`EDIT`
Through a little research, I found that the new function does exactly what it says, it creates a​ new object every time it is called.

Comment: Have you looked into online tutorials that cover the Java basics? Oracle even has their own [set of tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) which cover all the topics you're questioning about. Please express the research you have done, as your post is currently [not fit for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and may not receive the feedback you expect.

Comment: No I had no idea about their tutorials! this will help me out a lot thank you so much.

Comment: +1 for starting with Processing, great choice!  Most people just dive into Java, which is a VERY VERY VERY BAD idea.  Starting with Processing and learning from there is much easier and better.

Comment: The line you mention specifically is a "for statement", described here in the Oracle tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I'm sorry I have been looking what the new function does on stack overflow for a while and didn't come across that one ill take mine down since its basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stars` variable is an array.  It has 1200 rooms because of [1200] of the first line.

[image]

For example, if you have an array like this

String[] a = new String[3]

you just created three spaces for String values. You can put values.

```
a[0] = "a"
a[1] = "b"
a[2] = "c"
```

Please note that an index for the first space is 0. (Don't get confused.)

Now,

```
void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
   stars[i] = new Star(); 
  }
}
```

[image]

Line 8 is about Java For loops.

`stars.length` - length() method will tell you the length, which is 1200
`int i` variable will start from 0 and `int++` will increase each time by 1. 
Like 0 , 1, 2, 3 ,4 ..... until     `i < starts.length` i reaches 1199.

I don't know about your `Star` class, but for your 1200 spaces

```
stars[0] = new Star();
stars[1]  = new Star();
// This goes on until
starts[1199] = new Star();
```

Star class will put whatever value it is supposed to set for 1200 spaces.